# Why do Firefox and Chrome render this scrollable region in a flex child differently and how do I make Firefox work as Chrome does?

Tags: css, scroll, flexbox

I am constructing a toolbar with a dynamic amount of elements to the right side of a page with height that always equals viewport height.

The toolbar is split in two regions, and if too many elements are included, the upper region is supposed to scroll.

However, with my solution, in Firefox the scrollbar is above the elements. In Chrome, it renders just as expected and shifts the elements to be scrolled to the side.

I searched some time, but my search words are overlapped with older issues regarding min-height:0 and min-width:0 for a flex child issue. The issue where the scrollbar itself is just above the scrollable region's content I could not find.

Reproduction on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3o65an7m/4/

Reproduction also copied here, but imo easier to see the issue on JSFiddle:

```css
html {
  height: 400px;
}

body, .wrap {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 0;
}

.right-bar {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 0;
}

.upper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.footer {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.b {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: red;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="right-bar">
    <div class="upper">
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="lower">
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">Text</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Image comparison; left FF, right Chrome. I desire the behaviour to always be as visible in Chrome:

[image: Image showing difference in render between Firefox and Chrome; in Firefox, scrollbar is above elements, in Chrome, elements are shifted to the left to avoid collision with scrollbar]

Comment: FWIW, Safari has the same behavior as Firefox. And you can have that behavior in Chrome by setting  `overflow-y: overlay`.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but I'd actually need it the other way around. Regarding the answers it seems I'll have to just find a completely different solution, especially since this is a problem in Safari, too.